# Too many problems on tables in Tinymce?

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

im working on a CMS it is almost finished 
but im struggling serious unfamiliar problems in WYSIWYG editor.

i was first using ckeditor but after experiencing problems with it i switched to tinymce.
some problems are solved but this time someother problems showed up.

problems occuring especially on tables.

1-Anchor element underline removal not working

2-Duplicating Phone numbers
--->might be due to skype phone number converting toolbar

3-too many &nbsp;s how to clean those why even those are there?

4-how to convert

```
<p>text</p>
```

back into just

```
text
```

because tinymce converting some texts into p element *automatically if it's not the client doing it unknowingly.
*=even though i did that force_paragraph:false setting.

5-As client reports : sometimes cursor turns into loading cursor and wysiwyg editor causes browser to stuck.not even allowing to click links outside of the editor.

6-as i experience sometimes it really does stuck and not allow you to edit anything at all.

here is that problematic page created with tiny_mce and causing lots of errors in process of editing:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some answers

> **2**-Duplicating Phone numbers --->might be due to skype phone number converting toolbar

Might be - this cannot ba a tinymce related problem.

> **3**-too many & nbsp;s how to clean those why even those are there?

Browsers will show several spaces (character code 32) as a single one. Thus & nbsp;s are inserted alternating instead of natural spaces.

> **4**-how to convert
>
> text
>
> back into just   text

Tinymce is a rte editor and will generate html code. In order to be able to style editor content, the content need to be wrapped inside a block element - eighter ps or divs. You may use server side code to remove tags.

> **6**-as i experience sometimes it really does stuck and not allow you to edit anything at all.

Please describe a bit more in detail - there needs to be a reason for this.